# Java Strings subtle differences

Tags: java, string

```
class Test {
    public static void main() {
        String s1 = null + null; //shows compile time error
        String s1 = null;
        String s2 = s1 + null;   //runs fine
    }
}
```

Can anybody please explain the reason for this behavior?

Comment: A question which might lead you the way: What type would you assign the expression "null + null" and why?

Comment: The first might presumably work if "null" always only referred to the lack of a String object, but, in fact, it signals the absence of ANY object, and hence "+" has no object type to guide the choice of a specific meaning for "+".

Comment: Well null is explicit, so null + null is just one of those low hanging fruit checks during compile time, but variables can become null during run time.  In the second case, the compiler would have to check that s1 is null all the way up to the assignment of s2 in order to kick it out.

Comment: @Mike - If the null were replaced with a String variable set to null then the compiler would attempt to invoke String ops to handle it.  Would fail, though, because `concat` would be invoked with a null.

Comment: Also: this code is invalid because `s1` is declared twice. Maybe use different scopes by putting the two examples in different blocks?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This code:

```
String s1 = null + null;
```

tries to perform addition operation on two `null`, which is not valid.

while here:

```
String s1 = null;
String s2 = s1 + null;
```

You assigned `null` to `s1`. Then you perform concatenation of `s1` and `null`. The type of `s1` is `String`, so `null` in `s1 + null` will be converted to `"null"` string as per the String conversion rules, as in [JLS §15.1.11 - String Conversion:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)

> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string `"null"` (four
>   ASCII characters `n, u, l, l`).
>
> Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the
>   `toString` method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the
>   result of invoking the `toString` method is `null`, then the string `"null"`
>   is used instead.

and concatenation will be done as - `s1 + "null";`

Comment: @BheshGurung, Associativity isn't really relevant in this situation since there is only one operator present, but consider the expression `a + b + c`. Because `+` is left-associative, the expression is parsed as `(a + b) + c`. If it were right-associative, the expression would be parsed as `a + (b + c)`. (It's also possible for an operator to be non-associative, in which case the expression would either be a syntax error or have some kind of special meaning, depending on the syntax definitions.)

Comment: It won't be converted into the string `"null"`, will it? I thought it would just stay as a null pointer.

Comment: I'm actually mildly surprised that this works. The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) only says, "If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time." Nothing is mentioned about any case where string conversion is applied to *both* operands, which is necessary for this to work.

Comment: @Stendika: It gets converted for the `s1 + null` addition, not the `s1 = null` assignment.

Comment: @user2357112 And isn't `s1` of type `String`, in `s1 + null`? There is no type for `null`, when used directly, but when it's assigned to `String s1`, the operator will see the type of `s1`, and not that whether it is `null` or not.

Comment: Actually the first statement is "wrong" (depending how you interpret it), it's perfectly valid to write `(String)null + null`. The reason the first one doesn't work is that we cannot know what rules from the JLS we should even apply since null is untyped (could be a reference for an Integer for all we know which would rather change the semantics). With the cast the type is clear.

Comment: @Voo How does the validity of `(String)null + null` make my first statement wrong. By typecasting, you've clearly typed the `null` to `String`, while with `null + null`, there is no valid type for which `+` operation is defined. And that is what I've tried to say there.

Comment: @Rohit `(String)null` is still a null, so "tries to perform addition operation on two null, which is not valid" isn't really true since we just did. What you can't do is perform the addition on two *untyped* nulls.

Comment: It is saddening that this is the validated answer, when the affirmation that `The type of s1 is String, so null will be converted to "null" string"` is just plain wraong

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles Prove it. I've even attached the JLS link accompanying my claim. It clearly says, string concatenation will `null` will result in concatenating `"null"`.

Comment: Except there is no need for any conversion here, because a null value is already a valid value for a String (just like for any reference type). As for a proof, how about simply trying this snippet: `System.out.println(s1.length);`. If you are right, it will print 4, otherwise it will throw a NPE. Guess what it does?

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles I'm sure you misunderstood that statement. I was talking about conversion from `null` to `"null"` for the second `null` in `s1 + null`. And not the one assigned to `s1`.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 15):

The `+` operator as `String` concatenation only applies if one (or both) of the operands has type `String`.

[This is defined in the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18)

> If the **type** of either operand of a `+` operator is `String`, then the operation is string concatenation.

In

```
String s1 = null + null; //shows compile time error
```

the operands have the `null` type, ie. not `String`, so no string concatenation happens. Java then thinks you are doing an addition which also doesn't work on `null` types.

In

```
String s2 = s1 + null;   //runs fine
```

`s2` has type `String` even though it is referencing `null`, so string concatenation can happen.

Answer (score 9):

In below case, you are performing operation on two `null` and `+` operation is not defined for two `null`.

```
String s1 = null + null;
```

And in this one you are performing concatenation of `String` with `null`.

```
String s2 = s1 + null;
```

**And another interesting case is,**

```
String abcd = (String) null + null;
```

That will be resulted in "nullnull" string as you are casting `String` to `null` and again concatenation will be performed. so first `null` will be treated as `String`.

Answer (score 3):

From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> The Java language provides special support for the string
>   concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to
>   strings. String concatenation is implemented through the
>   StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its `append` method

Thus, at least the left operand must not be null since `StringBuffer.append(Object object)` accept `Object` (including `null`) as parameter.

Comment: +1 for referencing StringBuffer - I think that's an important omission in the accepted answer.  Your answer is less complete overall, though.

Comment: Yes, less complete since the majority of the concept had already been explained.

Comment: I think you've failed to explain how StringBuffer accepting null answers the question, though - this answer should show what the compiler converts the string concatenation to, to make it clear why neither of the two nulls causes a problem.  Also, I would suggest specifically mentioning the other answer that explains what you left out - otherwise this is just a competing answer that fails to answer the question.  (Actually, maybe I should provide a competing answer myself.)

Comment: Actually... I just tested this, and StringBuilder won't accept `append(null)` - it complains that it's ambiguous.  Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: Actually, you would have to cast to a specific type:  like `append((String)null)` in order to be able to select the right overloaded method. On the "concept" aspect, it accepts `null`, technically, a cast is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Basically this because you are dealing with literals, and because of that, the COMPILER is trying to perform an operation on those literal values.  It's happening at compile time, and there's nothing to do with two null values.

The compiler error you are getting is the equivalent of an exception -- the compiler doesn't know what to do with it, so it errors out and gives the types an explanation saying it doesn't work.