# Java's null value is added to the String

Tags: java

Yesterday I was working on an android project & found that `null` value too is concatenated to a String  also it effects the String length , while empty string doesn't have any effect. 
Why is it so ?

UPDATED QUESTION : Why is it so ? null is supposed to hold nothing !

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Sample
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
    String nullVar  = null;
    String emptyVar = "";


    String newNullVar = nullVar + "Some,String";
    String newEmptyVar = emptyVar + "Some,String";



    System.out.println(newNullVar + " & length is " +newNullVar.length());
    System.out.println(newEmptyVar +  " & length is " +newEmptyVar.length());


    }
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
nullSome,String & length is 15
Some,String & length is 11
```

[Output Online](http://ideone.com/7nib87)

Comment: What do you mean *"Why"* ? Do you want to know why Java (most languages in fact) is designed like this ?

Comment: This is part of the Java fundamentals.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Strings subtle differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969348/java-strings-subtle-differences)

Comment: Having `""` and `null` behave the same would *not* be useful.

Comment: It is so strange , possible duplicate got 20 upvotes and mine question is getting down votes .

Comment: @SachinGadagi It is not a duplicate at all! Your question is like: "why if i try to multiply two double and then to assign the result to an int the code is not compiled?" Or "why when i get the length of a String i use length() and for an array I use length?". These are very basic questions, it seems that you don't have the basis for programming in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `null` reference is rendered as `"null"` because the [JLS says so](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> - If the reference is `null`, it is converted to the string `"null"` (four ASCII characters `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`).

On the other hand, the empty string is a sequence consisting of zero characters, and this is how it is rendered.

Comment: `because the JLS says so` is the right answer. +1

Comment: Perfect username for an answer ;)

Comment: @Rogue Can you explain please :) ?

Answer (score 0):

because that way if you try to print a null abject, you will get a "null" that is a little more helpfull than a void. for example

```
Integer i;
try{
    i = Integer.parseInt(str);
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //we don't care
}
System.out.println(i);
```